# Unable to extract using Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter but able to do so in regex101

Tags: regex, performance, jmeter, performance-testing

Tried extracting values of multiple variables using regex101 and was able to do so, but on trying the same with Regular Expression Extractor unable to get extracted values.

I did google a lot on this and did quite a lot of trial and error but there was no luck or found anything similar on it.

```
input type='hidden' name='code' value='([A-Za-z0-9+= \-\_]+?)' \/>
<input type='hidden' name='id_token' value='(.*)' \/>
<input type='hidden' name='scope' value='(.*)' \/>
<input type='hidden' name='state' value='(.*)' \/>
<input type='hidden' name='session_state' value='(.*)' \/>
```

I want to extract value of below listed variables:
1.code 
2.id_token
3.scope
4.state 
5.session_state

Please refer :
[image: JMeter-RegExExtraction]

and

[image: 101Extraction]

Comment: You've select to use the `pcre` dialect while your actual tool uses `Perl`. I suspect it's just a matter of converting you pcre style regex to a Perl style regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. My expectation is that you should be using a single Post-Processor for single value. Otherwise you will have to think of [multiline regular expressions](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch06_07.htm)
2. In general [using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748) as:

   - regular expressions are hard to develop and/or maintain
   - regular expressions are very fragile and sensitive to markup changes

So I would recommend going for [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) instead, it is much easier, more human-readable and reliable than regular expressions approach:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T this worked for me.